# GZipStream 4G limit - total or currently streaming?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, gzipstream, sslstream

Have aa `GzipStream` feeding an `SSLStream`.

First time today noticed
"The gzip stream can't contain more than 4GB data."

```
at System.IO.Compression.FastEncoder.GetCompressedOutput(Byte[] outputBuffer)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean isAsync)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at ...
```

The Writer to the network is feeding in data faster than the Reader is getting the data. As such the cause of the error is unclear to me.

**Is this is a limitation on the total bytes written through the stream or is this is an issue with backlog getting the data out of the `GZipStram` and into the `SSLStream`?**

The Reader is able to unzip and use the data before the stream ends, so I never thought that there might be such a limit on total bytes written.

There doesn't seem to be a way to check the length.

**Could anybody share examples on how they handled this?**

Code outline:

```
TcpClient network = = new TcpClient();
network.Connect(m_config.Address.Host, m_config.Address.Port);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(network.GetStream(), true .. ssl bits
Stream outStream = new GZipStream(sslStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);

try {
    String nextMessage;
    while (messages.Dequeue(out nextMessage))
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nextMessage + "\n");

        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
} catch()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GZipStream and DeflateStream classes in .NET Framework 2.0/3.0/3.5 do not support reading/writing more than a total of 4 GB of data.

This limitation has been removed in .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Thanks.  Having closed the GZipStream and creating a new one I was having some trouble, recently diagnosed as issue with the other end of the connection not handling the end of stream and also starting afresh.